Easiest method (or tool) to queue commands/actions for a list of files?
Are there any tools to help automate the process of finding a list of files and executing a specific action in a queue?
For example, search all video files and run ffmpeg, etc.
I've found the 'at' set of batch commands which might be the best option? (I still need to get the list of files and create each command I think?)
An ideal helper tool would allow me to do something like: (?)
find ./ -iname '*.mp4' | <queue_tool> --execute "ffmpeg -i $file -o $other_variable"
